# Creating a list with multiple categoreis and options

Tags: custom-taxonomy, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to work out the best way to do the following.

I need to create a list of products. Each product will have a title, a short description a pack size or weight and an image. Clicking the product title will show the content description and image in an accordion box below the title.

There needs to be an editable list of Categories with child categories and possibly grand child categories. Each product may need to go into several categories. See image below.

[image: As show here]

The main category would be "Cheese / Sheeps Milk" then they would have a separate menu of the child and grand child pages. In the example The "Milk Type", "Cheese Type, "Country of Origin" and "Organic Cheeses" would be the second level and would not have any direct products, but the last level of categories would. Some categories would not need the final level.

I want to make it as simple and quick as possible for the site admin to add and edit lots of products.

From what I can see I have two main options..

1. I can use Advanced Custom Fields with a repeater field to create the list of products with their information, but then would need to somehow apply them to the right  categories. I could possibly use ajax to display the products on the right when the categories they are in are selected.
2. To create custom post types and taxonomies, but each product would have to be a new post and could create far more work, or at least waiting for pages to load for the admin. All product information would be displayed on the list page so there is no need to link to post page.

Which is my best option? I'm open to alternative if there is a better option.

If option 1 is the best... How would you implement it?

Comment: Whenever I can, I use Custom Post Types instead of ACF because when you have 50 or more custom fields under one post things will start to slowdown on the front-end and on the post edit page. You will need a better server with better php settings (more memory limit, more input characters per save).

Comment: A good point.. I don't think there will be that many items in each section.. There would be a page / post for each top level.. All cheeses would be in cheese section, but other types of product would have their own page it's own list of sub categories. I just worry about them having to add 25 pages for a list of 25 items when it can be in one fairly small table.